# Change buttons' font in inputAccessorView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios4

I can't find a way to change the font for the buttons in the `inputAccessoryView`. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: _prevButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Prev" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(prevButtonClicked)] autorelease];

Comment: I want to change this buttons font

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the font of a UIBarButtonItem, use this:

```
[buttonItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:26.0], UITextAttributeFont,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying for iOS 5.0+, you can use the `UIAppearance` proxy:

```
UIFont *font = // create your font
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIToolbar class], [self class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ UITextAttributeFont: font } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This code  will change the font for all `UIBarButtonItem`s (a.k.a buttons) in all `UIToolbar`s (including the one as `inputAccessoryView`) in your `UIViewController` subclass.